# Clipping of raster as a shapefile in r

Tags: r, raster, clip, rastervis

I want to clip a raster using shapefile in r as a shape of shapefile. I used crop function but it clipping as extents not as a shape. Please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crop, as stated in the manual pages, crops to the extent of the object, 
for your purposes you may use `raster::mask()`, with the same syntaxis of crop
mask function  "Creates a new Raster* object that has the same values as x, except for the cells  that are NA (or other maskvalue) in a ’mask’."
You may pass `inverse=T` so you get those values out of the spatialPolygon.